# Multiple Color Override in one text on Sketch

Tags: color, text, sketch-app, symbols

I have a question about Sketch symbols overrides. I have created a text box and have put some text inside and some hashtags. But the hashtags are in another color than the text.

I transformed my textbox into symbol. But I cannot change the color of my hashtags in the overrides section...

Do you have a way to change this color with a plugin or something ?

Sorry for my poor English :-)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot have multiple color in one item symbol.

What you can do here to **solve** this problem is

To create 2 separate text box next to each other and create a symbol by grabbing both of them together. 
Then you will have 2 different fields to override. one for your text and one for the hashtags.

[image]